# how to make the expiration date of a cookie read only?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

There is a website in which I do log in frequently, but I am tired of that process. Therefore I want to set the expiration date of the cookie longer because the site only sets the expiration date for two hours! After changing the expiration date of the cookie I want to make that read only because each time I reload the website page, it resets the expiration date.
Does anybody have any solutions?
I have tried EditThisCookie extension but it seems it cannot make the cookie read only!
Thanks

Comment: You can't make a cookie readonly. A cookie should have a path variable. which referes to the site path it belongs. That path have full control over the cookie

Comment: Have you thought about using a password manager? Some of them can log you in automatically, which would solve that step for you.

Comment: I don't know anyone that does that. Can you give me some examples?